# Вложенный запрос в Mysql

Tags: mysql, база-данных, запрос

Нужно составить запрос, который будет подсчитывать и одновременно выводить данные. Для большего понимания моих мыслей представлю пример ниже.
Имеется таблица в которой есть данные

```
id_post | name

1 | test1_1
1 | test1_2

2 | test2_1
2 | test2_2
2 | test2_3

3 | test3_1
3 | test3_2
```

В итоге мне нужно подсчитать одинаковые id_post и вывести данные в таком виде

```
id_post | name

2 | test1_2

3 | test2_3

2 | test3_2
```

Comment: как name выбирать? сейчас он так выводится, а потом может в другом порядке их отобразить

Comment: Его желательно сортировать. Он меня мало волнует,т.к. он для данной задачи не нужен.

Comment: ну если name не нужен, то зачем его выбирать? можно просто `select distinct id_post from table_name`, либо `select id_post, name from table_name group by id_post` - mysql позволяет сделать так без агрегатных функций над name, только выберет он произвольное значение (так считать будет правильнее, чем считать, что выберет первое, хотя бы потому что сортировка здесь не задана явно)

Comment: Мне нужно подсчитать все одинаковые id_post, а не произвести группировку. На словах все просто: 1) Взять все одинаковые id_post 2)подсчитать их и в конечном выводе показать то, что я указал в примере

Comment: Без группировки у Вас такое вряд ли получится.

Comment: @lolokot, так если вам подсчитать надо, то так и надо в вопросе писать, просто в примере это не так ясно (показалось что надо post_id выводить). Подсчитывается все просто: `select post_id, count(1) as cnt from table_name group by post_id` - в результате получите post_id с его количеством в cnt

Comment: Я имел в виду, что пример @BOPOH не является правильным. p.s. читаю свои сообщения и просто поражаюсь) Пора уже спать, но эту задачу надо решить до сна ((

Comment: @lolokot Что вообще не понятно как вы хотите получить строку `3 | test2_3` и что она значит. `test2_3` встречается только 1 раз и с ID отличным от 3. Что такое 3 в этой записи результата ?

Comment: @Mike id_post это не уникальная запись для данного name. Я просто привел 2 поля, которые меня нужны. Каждая строка имеет свой уникальный ID

Comment: @BOPOH спасибо. Видно нужно отдыхать, раз я уже не понимаю куда ставлю count () А можно еще прикрутить сортировку DESC для name, до формирования группировки?

Comment: @lolokot Кажется я начал понимать, это кол-во id_post, но какое имя вы хотите рядом с этим кол-вом, любое из тех что были ? И странно это выглядит, без самих id_post в выводе. Было бы логичнее видеть id_post=1 и кол-во 2 рядом с ним, ну и может быть минимальное имя рядом

Comment: @Mike Смотрите я беру общее кол-во одинаковых id_post и забираю последнее имя у этого одинакового id_post в примере я показал это.

Comment: @lolokot "Послденее" при какой сортировке ? max(name) не подходит ?

Comment: @Mike нет, не подходит

Comment: @lolokot Но у вас там присутствует какая то сортировка ? поточу что без нее это самое "последнее" вообще невозможно гарантировать

Comment: @Mike а можно ли сперва сортировку сделать, а вложенным запросом все остальное? запрос уже дали мне select post_id, count(1) as cnt from table_name group by post_id

Comment: @lolokot Нет - сначала сортировка а во внешнем запросе группировка,  смотрите мой ответ

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(id_post) as cnt, name from test group by id_post;
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо определится с порядком сортировки записей, которая будет выдавать вам правильный порядок имен в пределах одного id, причем должна быть возможность задать обратную сортировку. Предположим у вас есть еще 1 поле с датой, и надо выдать name на последнюю дату, тогда запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
select count(id_post), name
  from (select id_post,name
          from table
         order by id_post,date desc
       ) A
 group by id_post
```

Это происходит потому, что MySQL при группировке и отсутствии агрегатной функции от какого то поля берет значение этого поля из первой записи в группе